# Web Api 2 responds very slowly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm using WebApi 2 for my server REST api. 
On localhost it works quite well. But on the server it responds very slowly.

I noticed that at first the response takes very long time and after a while it gets better and it response almost immediately. But after while of none request it gets slowly again. I have to wait for response almost 10-20 secodns and normally it takes 1-2 seconds max.

Caching on the server is set. 
It seems to be something with sleeping deamon of the service?
Do anybody know, what is wrong? Is there any settings to improve this?

For my test data I'm sending very simple json object, so certainly it is not about  slow internet connection.

Comment: How are you hosting it on your server - in IIS?

Comment: The default timeout for ASP.NET on IIS is 20 minutes. That means the App pool recycles and the application has to JIT again.

Comment: I'm hosting it on shared server with decent spec. 20 minutes seems fine, but it stops responding (gets slowly) after 1 minute or so..

Comment: How much data are you sending?

Comment: Just login informations like "grant_type=password&username=User0&password=Password0" or {"Sale":11 , "VisitId":6, "Products" : [ { "ProductId":16 ,  "DistributorId":6, "Count":2 }, { "ProductId":8 ,  "DistributorId":1, "Count":3 } ]} just very simple json objects like this..

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Or using Glimpse?

Comment: No. What does it mean? Is it some kind of testing?

Comment: Glimpse is a nuget package that you can add to your solution and it will give you a complete profile of your application. http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: It seems that web service falls asleep in 30-60seconds after last request. If it is awake it responds immediately, but after that I have to wait much more time.

Comment: So the problem is, that my shared hosting offers only 100MB RAM and my web service needs about 250MB so hosting recycles my service very often and then it gets slowly :-/